# Ext4 for Linux and Fuse with OS X?

Tags: macos, partition, filesystem, ext4

System: El-Capitan 10.11.5, Macbook Air 2013-Mid, SSD 128 GB. I would like do a new partition in my SSD. Install Ubuntu on it side-by-side with OS X. I have documents which I would like to use by both systems.

### Proposal 1 with SSD

- OSX in OSX Extended.
- Linux in ext4.
- Use fuse if need files of Linux in OSX. Not sure how well this works.

I am unsure how you can create a symlink from Linux-ext4 to OSX-extended through fuse.

### Proposal 2 with SSD + big HD in memory card slot

- OS X in OSX Extended.
- Linux in ext4.
- Big HD in ntfs. Both systems should be able to read it. However, possible conflicts with Linux permissions.

How well will symlinks work to 2nd HD from OSX and Linux? Can both systems use `ntfs` format?
Is there any better format which both systems (Linux and OSX) can use?

---

How can you initiate ext4 for OS X's Linux partition and use it with OS X?

Comment: On a PC, I have a default install of Linux Mint 17.1, which does not have `hfsprogs` installed, and it automatically mounts and reads my external USB drive that is formatted Mac OS Extended (Journaled) with OS X 10.11.4 installed on it, created on my Mac.  So I don't understand why you'd make a statement like "_Current OS X Extended format cannot be read with Linux._".  Update: Looks like you edited your OP a couple of times and removed your original statement I quoted.

Comment: @user3439894 I am enough newbie here. I have had difficulties of using OSX fileformat with my Linux installations. Problems with symlinks and Linux permissions. I do not know about `hfsprogs`.

Comment: Although this may not be ideal for other reasons, the only sure way I know of in which permission conflicts can be avoided between Linux and OS X from a shared filesystem standpoint is to use a FAT32 volume to share files between the two, as it does not support file permissions and hence no permissions conflicts.

Comment: @user3439894 Great! What are limitations of using FAT32 there? Can I use symbolic links etc? Please, feel free to make your comment an answer because I almost forgot FAT32.

Comment: The individual file size limit is 4GB. As to symlinks, I do not have a setup with an Ext4 volume on the same drive to test against however I just created a symlink on a FAT32 USB drive to a file on the Mac, formatted Mac OS Extended (Journaled), and when double-clicking the symlink it opens the file. I know this is not a complete test but it's what I have at the moment. As to other features supported/not supported under FAT32, Google is your friend. :)

Comment: @user3439894 I am just worried about my Matlab projects which will be located in fat32 media. I think I should do symlink to my OSX partition. However, I am not sure how well Matlab can use such codes.